# Is the inverse of $(x+y, zw+z+w, y^2)\subset Q[x,y,z,w]$ under inclusion $g: Z[x,y,z,w]\to Q[x,y,zw]$ in $Z[x,y,z,w]$ still be $(x+y, zw+z+w, y^2)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, groebner-basis

In general, suppose
$g: Z[x,y,z,w] \to Q[x,y,z,w]$
is the canonical inclusion, and $I=(f_1,...,f_n)\subset Q[x,y,z,w]$ be an ideal such that for each $f_i$, its coefficients are 1, and for each two generators $f_i, f_j$, their terms are different with each other.
My questions is whether the inverse image of $I$ under the inclusion $g$, for which is the ideal of $Z[x,y,z,w]$, i.e. $Z[x,y,z,w]\cap I$, still has the form $I=(f_1,...,f_n)$?

If the coefficients are not 1 and two polynomials have common terms, there has counterexample, for example
$I=(x-y, x+y)\subset Q[x,y,z,w]$, it is clear that $x\in I$, however, $x$ is not in$Z[x,y,z,w]\cap I=(x-y, x+y)\subset Z[x,y,z,w]$.

Especially I am interested in the following two ideals:
$I_1:=(x+y,zw+z+w,y^2)$
$I_2:=(x+y+z+w+xy+xz+xw+yz+yw+zw, xyz+xyw+yzw+xzw+xyzw)$
I want to ask if the inverse image of these two ideals in $Z[x,y,z,w]$ still keep the form?

Comment: It seems like you answer the question from the first paragraph in the second paragraph - you know that the answer is no.  Therefore, it may be better to clarify your question (and start with the question of interest).

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, a generalized version of this question is "Let $\phi:R_1\rightarrow R_2$ be a map of commutative rings with identity, and let $\phi':R_1[x_1,\dots,x_n]\rightarrow R_2[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be the corresponding map.  Let $I=(f_1,\dots,f_m)$ be an ideal in $R_1[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.  Under what conditions does $\phi'^{-1}(\phi'(f_1),\dots,\phi'(f_k))=(f_1,\dots,f_k)$?"

Comment: Hi, thanks for you comment. For your first comment, in my first paragraph, I add some conditions, I require all of the coefficients should be $1$, but in my second paragraph, $x-y$ has $-1$ as coefficient; Moreover, my second assumption is that the terms should be different with each other, but the polynomials $f_1=x+y$, $f_2=x-y$ has the common term $x$ and $y$ .

Comment: For you second comment, yes this is a more general version, but I am not sure there are answers for this version. So in my question, I restrict $R_1=Z$ and $R_2=Q$ and $\phi$ be an embedding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I=(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and $J$ the corresponding ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.  In other words, $J=I\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $G$ be a (strong and reduced) Groebner basis for $I$.  Note that $G$ is a Groebner basis for $J$ as well: Let $g\in J$, then $g=\sum h_i f_i$ where $h_i\in\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.  For a large enough $N\in\mathbb{Z}$, $Ng = \sum (Nh_i)f_i$ is in $I$ since $Nh_i\in \mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.  Thus, the leading monomials of both $I$ and $J$ are the same.

If any $f\in G$ has nontrivial content (that is, the $\gcd$ of the leading coefficients), then $J\cap\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]\not=I$, by dividing through by the content.  On the other hand, if all the leading coefficients of elements of $G$ are $1$'s, then $J\cap\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]=I$.  In particular, the division algorithm will never produce a fractional coefficient and the algorithm will be identical in both $I$ and $J$.

In your examples, graded-reverse-lex Groebner bases (as computed by Macaulay2) have Groebner bases with every leading coefficient $1$, so the intersection is an equality.

Note: In the case where the Groebner basis elements have leading coefficient not equal to $1$, but are content free, the situation is more complicated: $(2x+y)$ has the desired property, but $(2x+y,3y+2z)$ does not have the desired property.  There are content-free Groebner bases for both ideals, but the leading coefficients are not $1$ in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to ask whether your answer use the the condition: every term should be different? Because if there has common term, for example, considering the ideal $I=(x+y,x+z,y+z)$, in $Q[x,y,z]$, $x\in I$, but $x$ is not in the inverse image.

Comment: And by the way, is there still has a definition of Groebner bases over $Z[x_1,x_2,...x_n]$?

Comment: The Groebner basis for the $I$ you mention has $2z$ in it, so the distinctness of terms is captured by these conditions (in this case).

Comment: Strong Groebner bases are for polynomial rings over Euclidean domains.  See this open access [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-56/issue-1/Effective-computation-of-strong-Gr%C3%B6bner-bases-over-Euclidean-domains/10.1215/ijm/1380287466.full) for references.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So in this question, we first need to use the Macaulay 2 to compute the Groebner base of of ideal in $Z[x,y,z,w]$, if the coefficients are all $1$, then we can say the inverse image keeps the form right? In Macaulay 2, we use the following function: g=gb I,  gens g. Is my understand correct?

Comment: Any order should work in Macaulay2.  You don't need all the coefficients to be $1$, just the leading coefficient.

Comment: For Macaulay2 code, you can be a bit fancy, the following code computes and prints out the leading terms of the Groebner basis.  "ZZ[x,y,z,w];I=ideal(x+y,x+z,y+z); netList first entries leadTerm gens gb I"

Comment: What do you mean "any order"? Is the total order we give for the polynomial ring? By the way, the second ideal I interested, which I denote it $I_2$, is also keep the form? Because I use the Macaulay 2 to compute the Groebner base, and the coefficient has 2

Comment: Any monomial order should give you information, I'm not sure if one will work better than another.  As for $I_2$, I get that the leading terms (using grevlex) are $x^2y^2z$, $xw$, and $y^2zw$, all of which have coefficient $1$.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like a magic! I also have an extra question, can we use the Macaualy 2 to tell an ideal $I$ in $Z[x,y,z,w]$ is prime or integral closed? I only know we can do it over $Q$ or $F_p$.

Comment: I'd suggest contacting the [Macaulay2 google group](https://groups.google.com/g/macaulay2) for additional questions.  There are many people (including myself) there who can help with specific Macaulay2 questions.